# Modern solution to inject dependencies in Service with Dagger

Tags: android, service, dagger-2, dagger

## Can`t inject dependencies in service with Dagger

Spent a lot of time on finding solution for this question, but all answers is a bit old (2018-2019) and cant be implementend in that way as in answers.

Now my code is:

**AppComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class, DomainModule::class, DataModule::class, AppModule::class, ServiceModule::class]
)
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(app: Application)

    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)

    fun inject(networkService: NetworkService)
}
```

**Application class**

```
class App : Application(), HasAndroidInjector {

    lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .appModule(AppModule(context = this))
            .build()
        appComponent.inject(this)
        
    }

    override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector
    }
}
```

**NetworkService**

```
class NetworkService : Service() {

   @Inject
   val someDependency:SomeDependency


    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.e(TAG, "Service create")
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
     }
}
```

**ServiceModule**

```
@Module
abstract class ServiceModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeNetworkService(): NetworkService

}
```

I providing context in **AppModule**

```
@Module
class AppModule(val context: Context) {

    @Provides
    fun provideContext(): Context {
        return context
    }
}
```

At this moment app crashes with this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.xxx.xxx.service.NetworkService: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dispatchingAndroidInjector has not been initialized

Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dispatchingAndroidInjector has not been initialized
      at com.xxx.xxx.app.App.getDispatchingAndroidInjector(App.kt:18)
      at com.xxx.xxx.app.App.androidInjector(App.kt:34)
      at dagger.android.AndroidInjection.inject(AndroidInjection.java:177)
      at dagger.android.AndroidInjection.inject(AndroidInjection.java:130)
      at com.xxx.xxx.service.NetworkService.onCreate(NetworkService.kt:78)
```

Tried a lot of different solutions but they was too old and some classes is deleted at this moment. I tried to do something that will looks like solutions but this with no success

Comment: Does it help to have your App subclass [DaggerApplication](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/DaggerApplication.java)? That class has some extra protection around `injectIfNecessary`, though only ContentProvider is created before the Application: Services are supposed to be OK. Note that the other supported Android injection solution is Hilt (https://dagger.dev/hilt/), though that is enough extra build machinery that it might be more productive to get your use of `dagger.android` working first.